# How to run scala code from terminal

Tags: macos, scala, terminal

I have a simple `Scala` code that i want to run from osx `Terminal`.
Currently, my code runs in `intellij`.

```
object test
{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  {
     // my code
  }
}
```

So i have this `.scala` path:

```
/Users/rdave/projects/test.scala
```

This is what i have tried from osx `Terminal`:

```
scala /Users/rdave/projects/test.scala

scalac /Users/rdave/projects/test.scala
```

And got `command not found`

Comment: Try making your object "extend App" and running "sbt run" in your terminal

Answer (score 2):

> command not found

Is generated by the terminal, signaling that it can't find your executable

As the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/install.html) suggest:

> **Path and Environment**
>   For quick access, add scala and scalac to your path. For example:
>
> ```
> Environment     Variable        Value (example)
> Unix            $SCALA_HOME     /usr/local/share/scala
>                 $PATH           $PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin
> ```

After this, you will be able to call `scala` and `scalac` without any errors.

Comment: I know how to add path in windows but where to add it in osx ?

Comment: This might help http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.Vsx1-nV97eQ

Comment: How can i found the scala path ?

Comment: Just check where you unzipped it (something like `scala-2.11.7/`). that's your path, since Scala doesn't install

Comment: i adde the path into the folder where the file test.scala is inside and still when running the commend scala test.scala --> command not found

Comment: Maybe easier, check which `Scala` folder intellij is using and add that to the path. Also, you need to close and reopen the terminal for this to take effect

Comment: OK i have the path (/Users/dave/projects/src/main/scala) and inside this folder (scala) i have my .scala file and still command not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104314/discussion-between-alex-tartan-and-david-hol).

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, put your code in the "standard" directory structure (your scala class would therefore end up in /Users/rdave/projects/myproject/src/main/scala/) and run sbt console. You will have access to all your code and be able to use the REPL for experimentation.